# WebSocket connection is not working when script is loaded from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, requirejs

So, i have simple webSocket connection script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set web scocket connection
    var wsConnection = new WebSocket('wss://websocket.lh:4443');
    // web socket on open action
    wsConnection.onopen = function() {
        // web socket
        wsConnection.send(JSON.stringify({
            'action': 'subscribe',
            'channel': '{{ app.user.webSocketToken }}'
        }));
    }
    // web socket on recive data action
    wsConnection.onmessage = function(e) {
        // load notifications handler
        requirejs(["notificationsHandler"], function() {
            fn_notificationsHandler.getNotify(e);
        });
    };
});
```

This is working fine, but only when it's directly in my index/base.html, when i'm trying to include it as a external script like bellow the `onmessage` method stops working.

`<script src="/js/app/wsActions.js"></script>`

Also when i'm trying to do this with Require.js by typical way also not working. Why is that? Can anybody help?

Comment: do you get any errors in the dev console?

Comment: no, there is no tiny error :(