# Javascript Websocket closed unexpectedly when script is loaded externally

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

While building a chat application in Django, I used embedded javascript and it worked. But, if I write the same code in external javascript then the WebSocket gets closed. I have checked all the links and static file path. The script is loaded completely but the WebSockets gets closed after they open.

[Here's the tutorial from Official Django Channels website](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html#add-the-room-view), and that javascript is working in embedded form only not in an external script.

And, [here's my Github repo](https://github.com/m0hitnegi/chat-con/blob/master/interface/templates/interface/index.html) where I've implemented Websockets.
How can I write JS code in external script instead of embedded? I've Googled but found no help and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719970/websocket-connection-is-not-working-when-script-is-loaded-from-external-source) question hasn't been answered yet.

Here's the code I'm talking about and the websockets won't work if defined externally:

```
<!-- chat/templates/chat/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"/><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
</body>
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        var message = messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `How can I write JS code in external script instead of embedded?` so, in a file which you load using `<script src="file.js"></script>` ?? is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I want to write the code for WebSockets in an external file.

Comment: Didn't that comment just tell you what you need?

Comment: I did that, but WebSockets aren't working from external scripts. They are closing unexpectedly. When defined in the same HTML file, WebSockets are working fine, but when defined in the external file and load it in the HTML file like you said, WebSockets stops working.